# convert multiple variables into an array in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a class: fish and rectFish and instead of creating fish1, fish2, rect1, rect2, etc, I'd like to create an array to store the variable and then I'd like to loop through it to get the values to do certain things like decreasing score, etc. 
I have an empty loop and would like to put these values in the loop below:

```
      Fish[] fish = new Fish [6];
      Rect[] fishRect = new Rect [6];

    Fish fish1 = new Fish(200, 200);
    Rect fishRect1 = new Rect(200, 200, 50, 30);

    Fish fish2 = new Fish(100, 500);
    Rect fishRect2 = new Rect(100, 500, 50, 30);

    Fish fish3 = new Fish(100, 300);
    Rect fishRect3 = new Rect(100, 300, 50, 30);
```

And this is my loop (not really working)

```
for (int i=0; i < fish.length; i ++) {
            if (sharkRect.eats(fishRect[i])) 
            {
                /*eatFishSound.play();
                fish[i].die();
                fishRect[i].die();
                score.increasehealthBy();
                score.decreaseFish();*/
                System.out.print(fishRect[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array values in its constructor and then iterate them with *for-each*:

```
Fish[] fishArr = {
    new Fish(200, 200), 
    new Fish(100, 500),
    new Fish(100, 300)
};
```

For-each loop:

```
for (Fish fish : fishArr) {
    System.out.println("Fish: " + fish);
}
```

Is same (but more elegant) as:

```
for (int  i = 0; i < fishArr.length; i++) {
    Fish fish = fishArr[i];
    System.out.println("Fish: " + fish);
}
```

Or you can use a `List` for it:

```
List<Fish> fishList = Arrays.asList(
    new Fish(200, 200), 
    new Fish(100, 500),
    new Fish(100, 300)
);

for (Fish fish : fishList) {
    System.out.println("Fish: " + fish);
}

// since Java 8:
fishList.forEach(fish -> System.out.println("Fish: " + fish));
```

Since Java 9 you can use `of` static factory method:

```
List<Fish> fishList = List.of(
    new Fish(200, 200), 
    new Fish(100, 500),
    new Fish(100, 300)
);
```

Comment: Thanks! can you edit the for loop to match something similar to mine?  for (int i=0; i < fish.length; i ++) {

Comment: sorry I'm relative new to java and we weren't taught that as yet.

Comment: @CharlesXavier I edited my answer to explain variants.

Comment: Thanks dude! one last question, I'm trying to draw it to the screen and I'm using this but it's not drawing:   fishArr[i].draw(g); graphics is already imported and it was drawing before the array.

Comment: You should create a new question for this. I don't know which graphics and how you use it without seeing your code...

Comment: Dont worry I got it! Thanks again!